# Upload files to Google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I go to Google drive, using the key (P12)

I can browse folders, get data about the files, get lists of files in the Google drive. But I can not upload the file to Google drive.

On the TEAM all set right (is owner)

Why not give me the possibility to save the file?

Sample code I successfully get a list of folders:

```
def is_file_in_folder(service, folder_id, file_id):
  try:
    service.children().get(folderId=folder_id, childId=file_id).execute()
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    if error.resp.status == 404:
      return False
    else:
      print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
      raise error
  return True
```

The example code I'm trying to save file:

```
def insert_file(service, title, description, parent_id, mime_type, filename):
  media_body = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
  body = {
    'title': title,
    'description': description,
    'mimeType': mime_type
  }
  if parent_id:
    body['parents'] = [{'id': parent_id}]

  try:
    file = service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()

    return file
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occured: %s' % error
    return None
```

Shows the error - [ERROR](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.BadStatusLine)

I assume that the file is trying to load, but something prevents him, as well as (resumable = True), he tries again and again, until the time.

What do I need to be able to upload files?

Tried using the code to create a folder in Google drive, but shows the error (The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file)

So how to get these rights?

Comment: I would start by determining what the actual HTTP status code value was that the server responded with and then figure out what it means.

Comment: I described in the question.

When you try to download the file shows:
exception httplib.BadStatusLine  

When you try to create a folder, error:
The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file

Comment: Sorry, I messed that. I just Googled the error messsage text and got [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=637) which seems to indicate it might be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.
It appears in the interface "Google Drive" were displayed right on the folder is read-only on this no one is able to upload files to it. Because of this, and give an error and are only permitted to read.

By the way, can someone know how to get a direct link to the file. This format?: http://google.com/my_file.mp3